# Cuál es el preview standard al desarrollar una app en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy desarrollando mi segunda app con Android Studio. El preview por default del AVD es un nexus 5. Para mí es muy importante saber cual debo usar como preview dado que los botones de la app los estoy haciendo por mi cuenta en photoshop. Asi que me gustaria saber cual debo usar?

Comment: Con preview te refieres al emulador que aparece por omisión? Yo diría que pruebes con todos los posibles de acuerdo al tamaño de pantalla, version que quieras soportar.

Comment: Con la cantidad de dispositivos que hay en Android en mi opinión no deberías centrarte solo en un preview. Diseña tu app para todas las resoluciones.

Answer (score 0):

No existe preview de AVD (Android Virtual Device) oficial, inicia con una sugerencia que es el Nexus 5 pero tu tienes que crear uno de acuerdo a tus necesidades: tipo, tamaño de pantalla, resolución, sistema operativo, densidad de pixeles, etc.

Las imágenes que debes crear deben ser de las densidades que manejara tu proyecto, no es una sola imagen ya que se mostraría correctamente en tu dispositivo pero en los demás se vería incorrectamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Editando.

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto siempre nexus 5, pero al programar debes saber que las dimensiones de las pantallas y resoluciones de estas son distintas dependiendo de la marca y modelo del dispositivo. Es por esto que se debe-puede desarrollar layout para diferentes resoluciones, y definir imágenes en diferentes resoluciones.

Te recomiendo que leer la documentación oficial: [Documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html?hl=es)

También te recomiendo echar un vistazo a las estadísticas que ofrece Android, sobre cual es el porcentaje de dispositivo y resoluciones: [Estadísticas oficiales](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

No hay un AVD por defecto, pero si quieres adaptar tu aplicación para diferentes resoluciones te recomiendo instalar un plugin de Android Studio, se llama **Android Drawable Importer**. Al instalarse y dar clik derecho en tu proyecto > new, se agregaron tres opciones, la opción "Batch Drawable Import" te permite cargar una imagen, estableces la densidad para la cual es esa imagen y automáticamente te genera la imagen para las demás resoluciones